# Docker: In Dockerfile, copy files temporarily, but not for final image

Tags: docker

I have a Java service I'd like to package, and the only thing the final docker image needs is the JAR file and a config file.  However, I need to run my `gradle` command first to build the JAR, but I don't want all the things that `gradle` uses to be in the result docker image.

Here's my current DockerFile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk
COPY . /
RUN ./gradlew shadowJar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "service/build/libs/service.jar", "server", "service/service.yml"]
```

You can see I have to `COPY` everything first so that I can run `./gradlew` (otherwise it says the command cannot be found).  But in the end, all I need is the `service.jar` and `service.yml` files.

I'm probably missing something, but how I can make everything available during the `./gradlew` build step, but only have the result image include the `service.jar` and `service.yml`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Docker introduced so called "**multi stage builds**". With them, you can avoid having unnecessary files in your image. Your `Dockerfile` would look like this:

```
FROM ubuntu AS build
COPY . /src
# run your build

FROM ubuntu
RUN mkdir -p /dist/
COPY --from=build /src/my.object /dist/
```

The principle is simple. In the first `FROM` you name your build. In the second `FROM` you can use the `COPY --from=`-parameter to copy files from your first build to your second. The second build is the one which results in an usable image later.

If you want to test the results of your build instead the resulting image, you can use `docker build --target build myimage:build .`. The resulting image only includes the first `FROM` in your `Dockerfile`.

Try to use the same base image für your "build" and the final image. Different base images might result in strange bugs or even segfaults.

For more information: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds

Comment: My situation is that - due to security reasons I am downloading the packages in the intermediate layer. Then, ADD'ing them to the final image. Followed by using RUN command to install the packages and delete the packages. My goal is to delete the downloaded packages once the RUN command installs them. Is there any way to a) combine the ADD and RUN into one layer; b) remove the ADD layer?

Comment: That is a complicated question for a comment. You would need a small script to extract the layer of the image and import it in a new Dockerfile, see for layer extraction as `.tar`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44030483/685551

Comment: Unfortunately, multi-stage builds are not feasible if the files to be copied from one stage to the other are scattered over the whole file system and may even change from run to run. (For example, the result of a `dpkg -i`.)

Comment: @TorstenBronger That is true, but I would not recommend to copy files in this way. The image from one stage to another might differ in an incompatible way. It is better to use the intended install scripts in an package like .deb. Especially if there are differences from run to run.

Comment: @variable There are two ways. 1. [--mount=type=secret](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/reference.md#run---mounttypesecret) 2. rm package and use `--squash` when build

Answer (score 7):

Another workaround would be to use a web server to pull in the data.

1. Start a web server, serving your temporarily needed files. You may use

   ```
   python3 -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1 &
   ```

   to serve the current directory, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http-server-cli
2. In your `Dockerfile` get the file, perform actions, delete the files in a single `RUN`

   ```
   RUN wget http://localhost:8000/big.tar && tar xf big.tar && ... && rm big.tar
   ```
3. Build image with `--network host` to be able to access `localhost`

Answer (score 5):

Building an image works as follows.

> ... The docker build command will use whatever directory contains the Dockerfile as the build context (including all of its subdirectories). The build context will be sent to the Docker daemon before building the image, which means if you use / as the source repository, the entire contents of your hard drive will get sent to the daemon ...

See https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/

I see no way to achieve what you want. There are two options:

1. Having all the build dependencies inside the image and build your JAR file inside the container. That bloats your image.
2. I would recommend to build your JAR separately and just `ADD` the executable and config files when they are build. That means all build dependencies must be available on your development environment, but your image is as small as it can be.

Comment: I see.  I think I'm mixing up my build steps.  I should just run `./gradlew shadowJar` first, and then `docker build`.  I was thinking `docker build` was for building your application, but it's just for building the image, and you should build your application separately.  Makes sense, thanks

Comment: +1 I personally like it to have a Makefile for convenience to do such things.

Comment: There's no reason why creating a Docker image with your JAR and dependencies can't be part of your Gradle build. This has the advantage that Gradle already has first-class support for exposing to you the paths of all the dependencies it needed to complete the build.

Answer (score 2):

There is an experimental build flag `--squash` to summarize everything into one layer.

For example, `docker build --squash -t <tag> .`

The documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_build/#options.

The Github discussion https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/332.

How to enable experimental features in the daemon? https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/cli/experimental/README.md

Answer (score 1):

I adopted various comments and came up with this solution using `DOCKER_BUILDKIT`. I copy `somefile.tar.gz` temporarily into stage 0, but that file is not present in the final image. The overall container size is reduced.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental

# File: Dockerfile
# Build:
#     DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t sometag -f Dockerfile $(pwd)

# =============================================================================
# STAGE 0 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# =============================================================================
FROM somebase as devel

COPY somefile.tar.gz /somemodules/
RUN cd /somemodules && \
    tar -xf somefile.tar.gz

# =============================================================================
# STAGE 1 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# =============================================================================
FROM same_or_another_base

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        rsync && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN  --mount=from=devel,src=/somemodules,dst=/somemodules \    
    rsync -I -K -a /somemodules/somefile/* /usr/local/somemodules/

RUN echo "/usr/local/somemodules/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/somemodules.conf
ENV PATH=/usr/local/somemodules/bin:$PATH

# a bunch of other stuff . . .

RUN ldconfig
```

Answer (score -3):

You could do this:

```
FROM java:7
COPY . /sourcecode
WORKDIR /sourcecode
RUN ./gradlew shadowJar && rm -rf /sourcecode
WORKDIR /
CMD ["java", "-jar", "service/build/libs/service.jar", "server", "service/service.yml"]
```

This uses the Docker official `java` image ([see repo](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/java/)).

The `RUN` line should create your `service.jar` and then remove all the source code you've `COPY`d before the layer gets created, so the source code will not be part of the final image. I'm assuming `gradlew` will also copy/install it to /service/build/libs, otherwise you should add that step.

Comment: The `rm` won't do much to debloat the image: `COPY` is in a different layer. It'll only remove whatever work files gradle generated, but the source code will still be in a layer below (even if hidden by rm).