# docker: extracting a layer from a image

Tags: docker

Let's take the whalesay images as an example. `docker history` shows the following:

```
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
6b362a9f73eb        17 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin:/us   0 B
<missing>           17 months ago       /bin/sh -c sh install.sh                        30.37 kB
<missing>           17 months ago       /bin/sh -c git reset --hard origin/master       43.27 kB
<missing>           17 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /cowsay               0 B
<missing>           17 months ago       /bin/sh -c git clone https://github.com/moxie   89.9 kB
<missing>           17 months ago       /bin/sh -c apt-get -y update && apt-get insta   58.58 MB
<missing>           18 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["/bin/bash"]             0 B
<missing>           18 months ago       /bin/sh -c sed -i 's/^#\s*\(deb.*universe\)$/   1.895 kB
<missing>           18 months ago       /bin/sh -c echo '#!/bin/sh' > /usr/sbin/polic   194.5 kB
<missing>           18 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:f4d7b4b3402b5c53f2   188.1 MB
```

I'd like to extract the layer that says `ADD file:bla`. Is there a tool/way for doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'extract'?

Comment: According to https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/image/spec/v1.md, a layer is a JSON file and actual change to the file system. So ideally the extraction will give me both

Answer (score 37):

In this specific case, it looks like the `ADD` command added the base image to the file system.  If you run `docker history --no-trunc docker/whalesay`, the full command is:

```
/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:f4d7b4b3402b5c53f266bb7fdd7e728493d9a17f9ef20c8cb1b4759b6e66b70f in /
```

`docker history` reports that particular layer is 188MB.  Let's look at these layers in more detail:

```
$ docker save docker/whalesay -o whalesay.tar
$ tar tvf whalesay.tar

...
-rw-r--r-- 0/0       197181952 2015-05-25 22:04 cc88f763e297503d2407d6b462b2b390a6fd006b30f51c8efa03dd88fa801b89/layer.tar
...
```

Looks like a pretty good candidate!  You can now extract that layer and pull files out of it.

```
$ tar xf whalesay.tar cc88f763e297503d2407d6b462b2b390a6fd006b30f51c8efa03dd88fa801b89/layer.tar
$ tar xf cc88f763e297503d2407d6b462b2b390a6fd006b30f51c8efa03dd88fa801b89/layer.tar etc/passwd
```

If you're looking to pull a particular file out of a layer, but you don't know *which* layer, you could do this.  First, extract all the layers:

```
$ tar xf whalesay.tar
```

Now you've got all the layers as individual .tar files.  Let's find a file:

```
$ for layer in */layer.tar; do tar -tf $layer | grep docker.cow && echo $layer; done
usr/local/share/cows/docker.cow
0523c5a0c4588dde33d61d171c41c2dc5c829db359f4d56ab896ab1c185ed936/layer.tar
cowsay/cows/docker.cow
40e8ae7bb4e5b9eaac56f5be7aa614ed50f163020c87ba59e905e01ef0af0a4f/layer.tar
cowsay/cows/docker.cow
f9bc8676543761ff3033813257937aeb77e9bc84296eaf025e27fe01643927cf/layer.tar
```

Finally, extract the file from the layer you want:

```
$ tar xf 0523c5a0c4588dde33d61d171c41c2dc5c829db359f4d56ab896ab1c185ed936/layer.tar \
      usr/local/share/cows/docker.cow
```

This will extract that file with the full path relative to the current directory.

```
$ cat usr/local/share/cows/docker.cow 
##
## Docker Cow
##
$the_cow = <<EOC;
    $thoughts
     $thoughts
      $thoughts     
                    ##        .            
              ## ## ##       ==            
           ## ## ## ##      ===            
       /""""""""""""""""\___/ ===        
  ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~   
       \\______ o          __/            
        \\    \\        __/             
          \\____\\______/   
EOC
```

Answer (score 11):

It looks like other people would also like to have this feature, but unfortunately right now it does not seem to exist.

See also
[this issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8039)
and here a
[related request](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/9304)
which got rejected.

If you're fine with saving the complete docker (`docker save`) and then extracting a tarball with your layer, then this is possible:

```
docker run -it <your image>
# do fancy stuff in the container
docker commit <your container> foobar # create image from container
docker history foobar # will show you the layers
docker save -o foobar.tar foobar # dumps container contents to foobar.tar
```

Now `foobar.tar` will contain the file system states from different times.  Inspecting this tarball shows, in my case, a file `repositories` with

```
{"foobar":{"latest":"fdf43d96e691c57e9afb4b85dba2e6745146a7ca9076c7284c6b2e1f93434562"}}
```

which indicates, that the latest layer is `fdf43...`.  You can get a tarball with the file system contents of this layer via

```
tar -x fdf43d96e691c57e9afb4b85dba2e6745146a7ca9076c7284c6b2e1f93434562/layer.tar -f foobar.tar
```

There is a tool,
[undocker](http://blog.oddbit.com/2015/02/13/unpacking-docker-images/),
which automated this process, but I'm not sure whether it will work with the current format of the saved tar file.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what you mean by "extract" but if you want to get further information about image, run

```
docker inspect <image_name>
```

You you want to get file, then run container from this image. Try

```
docker export <container_name> > abc.tar
```

after that, **extract** `abc.tar` and find your file.

Comment: That's basically what I want but I'd like to be able to specify a layer and not the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

While not capable of extracting a specific layer, the [docker-save-last-layer](https://github.com/brthor/docker-save-last-layer) command line utility is made to extract the last layer only. Combined with `docker build --squash` you can avoid exporting the base layers. This may help to accomplish your goals.

It works by using a patched version of the docker daemon inside a docker image that can access the images on your host machine. So it doesn't require doing a full `docker save` before using it. This makes it performant for large base images.

Typical usage is simple and looks like:

```
pip install d-save-last

docker build --t myimage --squash .
d-save-last myimage -o ./myimage.tar
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker is not capable of saving layers individually, however there is a tool on Github called dlgrab that claims to do it. https://github.com/aidanhs/dlgrab

Answer (score 1):

The [`regclient/regclient`](https://github.com/regclient/regclient) project does include a [`regctl blob`/regctl later](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/blob/main/docs/regctl.md#blob-commands) which allows to fetch a specific layer.

You can list layers with [`regctl image manifest`](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/blob/main/docs/regctl.md#image-commands).

Since [regctl v0.4.5](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/releases/tag/v0.4.5), you can even use ([PR 296](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/pull/296)):

- `regctl blob get-`file to fetch a file from a layer
- `regctl image get-file` to fetch a file from the image layers

Example:

```json
$ regctl image manifest busybox
{
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
  "config": {
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
    "size": 1493,
    "digest": "sha256:6858809bf669cc5da7cb6af83d0fae838284d12e1be0182f92f6bd96559873e3"
  },
  "layers": [
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
      "size": 764618,
      "digest": "sha256:df8698476c65c2ee7ca0e9dbc2b1c8b1c91bce555819a9aaab724ac64241ba67"
    }
  ]
}

$ regctl blob get busybox sha256:6858809bf669cc5da7cb6af83d0fae838284d12e1be0182f92f6bd96559873e3 | jq .
{
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "config": {
    "Hostname": "",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For docker images that contain one layer.tar, this works.

```
docker save myimage:latest | tar xO --wildcards '*.tar'  | tar xv myfile
```

First step extracts myimage as tar to stdout.
In the second step the '*.tar', which is in a dockerfile is usually layer.tar is selected and untared to stdout . In the third step we get the layer.tar from stdout and untar whatever file we want to pick