# Can I run an intermediate layer of a Docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When I fetch a Docker image from a repository I see that it pulls a bunch of layers with some ids, but when I try to run them using **docker run** it tells me that it can't find it.

Can I run a certain layer of a Docker image that I can see through **docker history < image_id >**, like a paleontologist digging to find something interesting?

**What I tried:**

```
docker pull ruby
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/ruby
693502eb7dfb: Already exists
081cd4bfd521: Already exists
5d2dc01312f3: Already exists
54a5f7da9a4f: Pulling fs layer
168cf3f33330: Pulling fs layer
021d84fef638: Pulling fs layer
168c3c107cd1: Waiting
f001b782a027: Waiting
```

Then:

```
docker run --rm -it 5d2dc01312f3 bash
Unable to find image '5d2dc01312f3:latest' locally
```

The question popped to me when I was pulling an image that I have build and published. I could see it clearly that one layer had almost 1.2 GB of size. It was the layer where I copied some files from the machine I used to build the image and on the next layer I cleaned and deleted some of those files as I was cleaning the image, but the total size of the image was about 1.5 GB which means that the big fat layer is of 1.2 GB is there. I just want to see if I can peek into that fat layer.

Comment: The big fat file is definitely there because it was added in a layer (dockerfile command) and removed in another layer. Docker does not support running multiple commands in the same layer but they have an experimantal `build --squash` option to squash image layers. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#squash-an-images-layers-squash-experimental-only

Comment: i think this is a new feature that squashs the fs layers into only one thus reducing the whole image size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So many years ahead, I came back to answer this question.
To peek at the intermediate layers the best and easiest solution is to export the docker image into archived format and than every layer will be a tar on its own inside the bigger tar which is of the docker image.

Let's take for example docker image of *tomcat:9.0*
To export it into tar format:

```
docker save tomcat:9.0 >tomcat-9.0.tar
```

When exported, inside it there can be found many Layers , each one is archived in its own tar file:

```
tar -tvf tomcat-9.0.tar 
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2022-09-02 12:41 1fdef6bff31128d5a1a41bdd5fea06be032ef59fd985da09842a252310b4afa3/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0               3 2022-09-02 12:41 1fdef6bff31128d5a1a41bdd5fea06be032ef59fd985da09842a252310b4afa3/VERSION
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             482 2022-09-02 12:41 1fdef6bff31128d5a1a41bdd5fea06be032ef59fd985da09842a252310b4afa3/json
-rw-r--r-- 0/0        20891136 2022-09-02 12:41 1fdef6bff31128d5a1a41bdd5fea06be032ef59fd985da09842a252310b4afa3/layer.tar
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2022-09-02 12:41 2ecda9f325b8b38fc5e0a2f1fed4526c517c087e909875abdf1ee4fbcab37b30/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0               3 2022-09-02 12:41 2ecda9f325b8b38fc5e0a2f1fed4526c517c087e909875abdf1ee4fbcab37b30/VERSION
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             482 2022-09-02 12:41 2ecda9f325b8b38fc5e0a2f1fed4526c517c087e909875abdf1ee4fbcab37b30/json
-rw-r--r-- 0/0       329143808 2022-09-02 12:41 2ecda9f325b8b38fc5e0a2f1fed4526c517c087e909875abdf1ee4fbcab37b30/layer.tar
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2022-09-02 12:41 2fe9b9ee40730bab9cf86153dd37fbddb4990dd09ba5b9f22e55eeae13063fe8/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0               3 2022-09-02 12:41 2fe9b9ee40730bab9cf86153dd37fbddb4990dd09ba5b9f22e55eeae13063fe8/VERSION
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             406 2022-09-02 12:41 2fe9b9ee40730bab9cf86153dd37fbddb4990dd09ba5b9f22e55eeae13063fe8/json
-rw-r--r-- 0/0        80354304 2022-09-02 12:41 2fe9b9ee40730bab9cf86153dd37fbddb4990dd09ba5b9f22e55eeae13063fe8/layer.tar
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2022-09-02 12:41 3fff0862317ff87f1d757557325c158d405afd7fd98f31544ce10cf3ad2bdaa7/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0               3 2022-09-02 12:41 3fff0862317ff87f1d757557325c158d405afd7fd98f31544ce10cf3ad2bdaa7/VERSION
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             482 2022-09-02 12:41 3fff0862317ff87f1d757557325c158d405afd7fd98f31544ce10cf3ad2bdaa7/json
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            3072 2022-09-02 12:41 3fff0862317ff87f1d757557325c158d405afd7fd98f31544ce10cf3ad2bdaa7/layer.tar
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2022-09-02 12:41 5cab171b0d1115044b08690329f32a7d99a546777097e935733a837100ef34c5/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0               3 2022-09-02 12:41 5cab171b0d1115044b08690329f32a7d99a546777097e935733a837100ef34c5/VERSION
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             482 2022-09-02 12:41 5cab171b0d1115044b08690329f32a7d99a546777097e935733a837100ef34c5/json
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            3072 2022-09-02 12:41 5cab171b0d1115044b08690329f32a7d99a546777097e935733a837100ef34c5/layer.tar
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2022-09-02 12:41 6b87b21c947802c9f53a614692b4369cc2d7aa951f64bf28cd1f8713e191894e/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0               3 2022-09-02 12:41 6b87b21c947802c9f53a614692b4369cc2d7aa951f64bf28cd1f8713e191894e/VERSION
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             482 2022-09-02 12:41 6b87b21c947802c9f53a614692b4369cc2d7aa951f64bf28cd1f8713e191894e/json
-rw-r--r-- 0/0        50671616 2022-09-02 12:41 6b87b21c947802c9f53a614692b4369cc2d7aa951f64bf28cd1f8713e191894e/layer.tar
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2022-09-02 12:41 895adbb30677e7148af6d01e295347bd6ddc7cd5d929ee8fc3d03aedac5fa857/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0               3 2022-09-02 12:41 895adbb30677e7148af6d01e295347bd6ddc7cd5d929ee8fc3d03aedac5fa857/VERSION
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            2588 2022-09-02 12:41 895adbb30677e7148af6d01e295347bd6ddc7cd5d929ee8fc3d03aedac5fa857/json
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            2048 2022-09-02 12:41 895adbb30677e7148af6d01e295347bd6ddc7cd5d929ee8fc3d03aedac5fa857/layer.tar
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           12431 2022-09-02 12:41 d4488b7f8c9b73c0f2e91f5e37990905ae3d34d55ea893b5e70b76fc7a2db1b7.json
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             661 1970-01-01 01:00 manifest.json
-rw-r--r-- 0/0              86 1970-01-01 01:00 repositories
```

To see and peek at the content of each layer, all what is left now is to decompress the tomcat tar and than decompress the tar of the targeted layer.

```
tar -xvf tomcat-9.0.tar
tar -tvf 6b87b21c947802c9f53a614692b4369cc2d7aa951f64bf28cd1f8713e191894e/layer.tar 
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2022-09-02 07:24 etc/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2022-09-02 07:24 etc/ca-certificates/
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 1970-01-01 01:00 etc/ca-certificates/.wh..wh..opq
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-10-16 18:09 etc/ca-certificates/update.d/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            5529 2022-09-02 07:24 etc/ca-certificates.conf
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2022-09-02 07:24 etc/default/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0              35 2022-09-02 07:24 etc/default/locale
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2022-09-02 07:24 etc/fonts/
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 1970-01-01 01:00 etc/fonts/.wh..wh..opq
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2022-09-02 07:24 etc/fonts/conf.avail/
[...]
```

Answer (score 36):

You can run an intermediate ***image*** of a Docker layer, which is probably what you want.

During your build you might need to inspect an image at certain point (step) in the build process e.g. in your Docker build output you'll see:

```
Step 17/30 : RUN rm -rf /some/directory
---> Running in 5ab963f2b48d
```

Where `5ab963f2b48d` is an image ID, and when you list your images, you'd see that ID in the list e.g.

```
$ docker image ls --all
REPOSITORY    TAG      IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
<none>        <none>   5ab963f2b48d   7 minutes ago  1.18GB
```

To run that image (with a terminal) for example, you can simply:

```
docker run -i -t 5ab963f2b48d /bin/bash
```

Also see: [Run a Docker Image as a Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497688/run-a-docker-image-as-a-container)

Comment: i think that is possible only in the buid machine where you have built the image, but how about a docker image that you grab from the docker hub registery

Comment: For me the `docker build` command is removing the layer before I can `docker run` it, so it just complains about not being able to find the image ID.

Comment: What about wsl2? In this way logs are different and it doesn't appear "---> running layer". I've also tested with DOCKER_BUILDKIT and `docker build --progress=plain`

Answer (score 8):

**Well, you can run an associated image if the final image was built locally on the same host machine.** Each layer would have an intermediate image associated with it. You can show these layers and their associated images by running `docker history <image-id>`

Images that are pulled from a registry won't have that. In that case, `docker history` will show the value `<missing>` to indicate that there are no images associated with these layers. Hence there is nothing to run.

The digests on the output of `docker pull` are digests of the layers not intermediate images and can't be run.

Here is a typical scenario:

1. **You build an image on a host:** An intermediate image will be
   created for each layer (this is done for docker build cache)
2. **You push the image to a registry:** Only the final image is pushed (which references all the layers), but none of the intermediate images are pushed.
3. **You pull the image on another host:** Only the final image is available now on that other Docker host.

You can read more about layers at [explaining-docker-image-ids](http://windsock.io/explaining-docker-image-ids/).

Comment: i understand you man the intermidiate images wont be accessible in the other host if the image get pusshed to the registry and pulled in an other host but my question was is it possible to access some intermidiate layers on a published docker images , i think it is possible since this is how docker works , i just want to know if there is a way to manually do it, you feel me

Comment: i think we need a docker hacker overhere to settle things straight

Comment: @achabahe I am not sure I understand what you mean by a "published docker image". Do you mean access a layer if there is no image associated with that layer?

Comment: final docker image that is published in a certain registery like dockerhub for instance

Comment: OK. I will try to dig deeper to be 100% sure when I have time, but my intuition is that the docker daemon would never allow you to create an image of a layer (and then potentially run it), or alternatively, manually manipulate the layers of an image. This would be dangerous from security point of view.

Comment: Awesome! , i will in my turn try to see if it is possible

Comment: This answer explains how to get files out of any layer ("missing" or not) in your docker image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44030483/804318

The main insight is that you can docker save an image into a tar-file which will contain files per layer.

Hoping this helps someone 3 years later...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, but if you are using Docker 1.10 or later, only with self build images. E.g., `docker history ruby` will output `<missing>` for all but the topmost layer, because they doesn't have a tag.

If you build it yourself they will have a tag and you can start them like normal.

Comment: i know about this possibility when a do a local build the intermidiate layers will be cached locally but what if i fetch a docker image from a repo and i am sure that in one layer there were some files that got deleted on the next layer. is'nt it possible to run only that specific layer and the previous ones and fetch those resources , iwill update my question

Comment: im sure this is possible by creating some metadata, but i dont know exactly how

Comment: yeah it is possible i think because the file system layer is overthere

Answer (score 2):

The most popular tool for examining image layers is currently [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive). It automates the `docker save` and a filesystem explorer in the CLI. By default, it's examining images from the local docker engine, so it typically needs access to the docker socket, e.g.:

```
docker run --rm -it \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    wagoodman/dive:latest ${your_image_name}
```