# docker pull an intermedia layer only

Tags: docker

A similar question as [Can I run an intermediate layer of docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42602731/can-i-run-an-intermediate-layer-of-docker-image), but the answers are for the image which you need build it locally.

My question is, I don't need `docker run` the intermediate layer, I can only pull the image from public registry server, such as hub.docker.com.

For example, for the history (layers) of an image like this:

```
$ docker pull ruby
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/ruby
e9afc4f90ab0: Already exists
989e6b19a265: Already exists
af14b6c2f878: Already exists
5573c4b30949: Already exists
11a88e764313: Pull complete
7bab57a324dc: Pull complete
0d7deb43995d: Pull complete
4315356f2eff: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:c750baf8de6d180aa48915655b79c35d93ef5665339860c1d608cb33e2ae873e
Status: Downloaded newer image for ruby:latest
docker.io/library/ruby:latest
```

can I get a tar from layer id `11a88e764313`?

#### Updates

I pulled the latest ruby image, the answer with `docker save` doesn't work

```
$ docker save -o layer.tar 11a88e764313
Error response from daemon: No such image: 11a88e764313
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I run an intermediate layer of docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42602731/can-i-run-an-intermediate-layer-of-docker-image)

Maybe try extrapolating what's mentioned there like: `docker save -o image.tar 168cf3f33330`

Comment: How do you know that you need this specific layer ? Layer is nothing but the result of an instruction of a Dockerfile...so why not just take this specific instruction and including it in your own dockerfile ?

Answer (score -1):

[Docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) should work.

`docker save -o myimage.tar 168cf3f33330`